# How to use S4 object programming in R

Tags: r, object, r-s4

What's wrong with my R script? I'm trying to use a vector of user-defined objects (here a vector of "Page" objects) within another user-defined object (here a "Book" object)

```
setClass("Page",
      slots = c(PageNo = "numeric",     #scalar
                Contents = "character") #vector of strings
)

setClass("Book",
      slots = c(Pages = "vector",       # Something wrong here? vector of pages ? "Page" or vector" or "list"
                Title = "character")    #vector of strings
)

setGeneric(name="AddPage", def=function(aBook, pageNo){standardGeneric("AddPage")})
setMethod(f="AddPage", signature="Book",
      definition=function(aBook, pageNo)
      {
          page1 = new("Page")
          page1@PageNo = pageNo
          aBook@Pages = c(aBook@Pages, page1) # Something wrong here?
      }
)

book1 = new("Book")
book1@Title = "Sample Book"
book1
book1@Pages
AddPage(book1, 1)
AddPage(book1, 2)
book1@Pages
```

Comment: Shouldn't the be a numPages numeric and a method for making a new Page item at 1+numPages and at 1 if numPages has length 0?

Comment: It works well with "numeric" PageNo. I checked with the script 'page1 = new("Page") \n\r page1@PageNo = 1'

Comment: A Page has its own page number but the Book needs to have a slot for the number of pages so that addPage can put a new Page in the proper location within the list of Pages. Pages should be the content and lastPage+1 or some such should be the default location for a new page with the possibility of revising content for existing pages. Or you can default to a number of pages derived from length Book@Pages.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that R does not use reference semantics, so `AddPage(book1, 1)` creates a copy of book1, and updates that. In the method you don't return the updated object, and book1 remains unchanged.

Update the method so that it returns the modified object

```
setMethod(f="AddPage", signature="Book",
      definition=function(aBook, pageNo)
      {
          page1 = new("Page")
          page1@PageNo = pageNo
          aBook@Pages = c(aBook@Pages, page1) # Something wrong here?
          aBook
      }
)
```

and assign the return value to the old variable

```
book1 = AddPage(book1, 1)
```

But this is a very inefficient approach -- the line `aBook@Pages = c(aBook@Pages, page1)` makes a copy of all existing pages (on the right-hand side, to create a longer vector; this will scale with the square of the number of Pages added to the book) and then copies the entire Book (for the assignment). In addition, creating individual objects is expensive and does not exploit R's 'vectorization'. A first step is to think of the object 'Page' as instead 'Pages', where the object models the columns rather than rows of a data frame. 'Book' then doesn't have vector of Page objects, but a single Pages object. This also implies a different approach to creating your 'book'.